# For a normed determinant function $\Delta$, show that the equality $|x|^2 |y|^2 - (x,y)^2 = \Delta(x,y)$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In the [book](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at [page 196](https://books.google.com/books?id=167rCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA196), it is given that

> In an 2 dimensional oriented inner product space, let $\Delta$ be a
>   normed determinant function then $$|x|^2 |y|^2 - (x,y)^2 =
> \Delta(x,y)^2$$

But how did we get this equation? I mean I do not remember any equation that includes norm, inner product and determinant function at the same time.

Note that, from the previous section, we get that
$$\Delta(e_1,e_2)^2 = \det(\langle e_i, e_j\rangle) \quad i,j = 1,2,$$
and $e_i$ is an orthogonal basis.

**Edit:** 
As @Spencer pointed out, RHS does not have to be zero.

Edit:
The notation $\det(\langle e_i, e_j\rangle)$ means that the determinant of the matrix whose i,j -th entry is $(e_i, e_j)$.

Comment: The lhs being the Schwartz Inequality does not imply that the rhs will be zero.

Comment: @Spencer "Inequality" right ? :) You are right, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No worries :). I tried looking at the text and the link you posted seems to be broken. An answer to your question would require a clear definition of $\Delta(x,y)^2$, which cannot be accessed without the text.

Comment: @Spencer I have edited the link. I should be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A determinant function on a two-dim space $E$ is a map: $\Delta: E\times E\rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ (or ${\Bbb C}$) which is bilinear (linear in both variables) and antisymmetric, i.e.: $\Delta(x,y)=-\Delta(y,x)$, $x,y\in E$.

A pedestrians way to the goal:
Let $e_1,e_2$ be an orthonormal base in $E$ and write: $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2$, $y=y_1e_1+y_2e_2$. By anti-symmetry of $\Delta$ we have $\Delta(e_1,e_2)=-\Delta(e_2,e_1)$ and $\Delta(e_1,e_1)=\Delta(e_2,e_2)=0$, so using bi-linearity:

$$ \Delta(x,y) = \Delta(x_1e_1+x_2e_2,y_1e_1+y_2e_2)= (x_1 y_2-x_2 y_1) \Delta(e_1,e_2)$$
This is unique up to a multiplicative constant (i.e. the value of $\Delta(e_1,e_2)$).
By pure algebra:
  $$ |x|^2 |y|^2 - (x,y)^2 = \left[ (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2) -(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2\right]= (x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2$$
and you get 
$$  |x|^2 |y|^2 - (x,y)^2 = \Delta(x,y)^2$$
provided that you normalize (whence the word "normed") so that $\Delta(e_1,e_2)=\pm 1$,
corresponding to declaring the area spanned by two orthonormal vectors
to be $\pm 1$.

A more conceptual approach that also works in any dimension $n$ goes as follows:

Let $M_{ij}=(x_i,x_j)$ be the matrix of the possible scalar products of the $x_i$'s with themselves. Also let $A_{kj}=(e_k,x_j)$ be the projection of $x_j$ onto $e_k$ so that 
  $$ x_j = \sum_k e_k (e_k,x_j) = \sum_k e_k A_{kj}$$
By linearity of $\Delta$ one has:
$$ \Delta(x_1,...,x_n) = 
\Delta( \sum_{k_1} e_{k_1} A_{k_1,1 },..., \sum_{k_n} e_{k_n} A_{k_n,n })
= \sum_{k_1}\cdots \sum_{k_n} \Delta(e_{k_1},...,e_{k_n}) 
A_{k_1,1} ... A_{k_n,n}$$
On the RHS, by anti-symmetry, only terms with distinct $k_1,...,k_n$ will survive. Thus the sum is over all permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ and, again by anti-symmetry, the value of $\Delta(e_{k_1},...,e_{k_n})$ is the sign of the permutation times $\Delta(e_1,...,e_n)$ , i.e. we get:
 $$ \Delta(x_1,...,x_n) = \Delta(e_1,...,e_n) \det(A) . $$
 Since $M_{ij} = \sum_k (x_i,e_k)(e_k,x_j) = \sum_k A'_{ik} A_{kj}$ we get by the product rule for determinants:
$$ \det M = \det (A' A) = \det (A)^2 = \Delta(x_1,...,x_n)^2$$
provided again that you normalize so that  $\Delta(e_1,...,e_n)=\pm 1$

Comment: Intiutively, the result $\Delta(x_1,...,x_n) = \Delta(e_1,...,e_n) \det(A)$ is plausible, but I'm not able to see this equality fully. Can you elaborate on that point ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $V$ is a real vector space with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Then for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$  there is a natural inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_k $ on its [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) $\Lambda^kV$, given by 
$$
(v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_k,w_1\wedge \dots\wedge w_k)_k = \det([(v_i,w_j)]_{ij}).
$$
It is possible that the book you are referring to uses the following definition:
$$\Delta(x,y):=\sqrt{(x\wedge y , x\wedge y)_2}$$
Then indeed you would have
$$
\Delta(x,y)^2=(x\wedge y , x\wedge y)_2 = \det \begin{bmatrix}
(x,x)& (x,y) \\
(y,x) & (y,y)\\
\end{bmatrix} = \vert x\vert^2\vert y\vert^2 - (x,y)^2.
$$

Comment: Well, I haven't studied exterior algebra, so proving the result by using some theorems in that subject does not really help.

Comment: Makes sense, I just tried to connect to some ideas where I have seen the formula before. However, you probably have seen the exterior algebra but under a a different name. Namely if you are studying $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, then you may interpret $x \wedge y$ simply as the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), did this show up in the context? In any case $x\wedge y$ stands for the parallelogram spanned by $x$ and $y$ and $\Omega(x,y)$ would be the parallelograms area, but once you're there you might as well accept the formula you are interested in as a definition.

Comment: Yes, I have seen cross product, as far as the author's definition, to be able to talk about cross product, we need our vector space to have the dimension 3, which is not the case in there.Plus, the author says that that determinant gives the square of the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors x, y, and z, so I don't think they are one to one related with the cross product.

Comment: But apart from those, I'm still thankful that you have posted your answer, I mean I will eventually study exterior algebra, so knowing the connections of the subject is a good thing, I think.